# Improving Performance and Resolving Race Condition in spring boot with Multi-Threading

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading, refactoring, race-condition

I made some modifications to the getCadInfo method in the following class to improve its performance by replacing Files.walkFileTree with Files.walk and adding multi-threading. However, I encountered a race condition, so I used the synchronized keyword to prevent it. However, the performance improvement I expected did not occur. If you were to modify this code, how would you do it?

This is my code

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class AsposeUtil {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CadController.class);
    private static final String cadDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator;

    @MeasureExecutionTime
    public Map<String, String[]> getCadInfo(String project) {
        try {
            ConcurrentHashMap<String, String[]> cadInfo = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            Files.walk(Paths.get(cadDir + project))
                    .filter(file -> !Files.isDirectory(file) && file.getFileName().toString().contains(".dwg"))
                    .parallel()
                    .forEach(file -> {
                        String title = file.getFileName().toString();
                        String path = file.toAbsolutePath().toString();
                        String index = extractCadIndex(path); // Extract the text from the cad file.
                        convertCadToJpeg(path); // Capture the cad file and create an image file.
                        path = path.substring(path.indexOf(project) + project.length(), path.indexOf(title) -1);
                        cadInfo.put(index, new String[] {path, title});
                    });
            return cadInfo;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("getCadInfo IOException: ", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private ByteArrayOutputStream convertCadToJpeg(String cad) {
            CadRasterizationOptions options = new CadRasterizationOptions();
            options.setPageHeight(200);
            options.setPageWidth(200);

            JpegOptions jpegOptions = new JpegOptions();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            jpegOptions.setVectorRasterizationOptions(options);
            synchronized(this){
                try (Image image = Image.load(cad)) {
                    image.save(stream, jpegOptions);
                } catch (ImageLoadException e) {
                    log.error("Image Load Failed: ", e);
                }
            }
            return stream;
    }

    private synchronized String extractCadIndex(String cad) {
        try {
            Set<String> index = new HashSet<>();
            try (CadImage cadImage = (CadImage) CadImage.load(cad)) {
                for (CadBlockEntity blockEntity : cadImage.getBlockEntities().getValues()) {
                    for (CadBaseEntity entity : blockEntity.getEntities()) {
                        if (entity.getTypeName() == CadEntityTypeName.TEXT) {
                            CadText cadText = (CadText) entity;
                            index.add(filterCadIndex(cadText.getDefaultValue()));
                        } else if (entity.getTypeName() == CadEntityTypeName.MTEXT) {
                            CadMText cadMText = (CadMText) entity;
                            index.add(filterCadIndex(cadMText.getText()));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (ImageLoadException e) {
                log.error("Image Load Failed: ", e);
            }
            return String.join(", ", index);
        } catch (ImageException e) {
            log.error("CAD File Disabled: ", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String filterCadIndex(String index) {
        String filtered = index.replaceAll(" ", "");
        int numCnt = (int) filtered.chars().filter(c -> c >= '0' && c <= '9').count();
        if (numCnt >= filtered.length() / 2)
            return "";
        return filtered;
    }
}
```

Comment: What performance improvements did you were expecting? What did you use synchronized for exactly?